# Heroku ignores system.properties file

Tags: java, heroku

```
cat system.properties 
java.runtime.version=11

git push heroku master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Gradle app detected
remote: -----> Spring Boot detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Building Gradle app...
remote: -----> executing ./gradlew build -x test
remote:        Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.3-all.zip
remote:        .....................................................................................................................................
remote:        To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
remote:        Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
```

Why still JDK 1.8 ?

Answer (score 0):

simple
`git push heroku develop:master`
since I'm on develop branch